# Holding event does not cancel when finger tap is lifted outside button

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have created a `Button` with a `Holding` event. This holding event works fine, when I tap and hold the finger on the button. First the event is invoked with `HoldingEvent.Started` and when I lift the finger it is invoked again with `HoldingState.Completed`.

My problem is that the event is never invoked if I tap and hold and drag the finger outside of the area of the `Button` and then lift the finger. I would expect it to invoke the event with `HoldingState.Cancelled`, but nothing happens.

Is there any way to know if the user has released the holding tap outside of the area of the `Button`?

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem. Have you been able to resolve it on your side?

Comment: No, I never found a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `CancelDirectManipulations()` to cancel ancestor `ScrollViewers'` scrolling manipulation seems to help.